# particulate matter in a colloidal substance

Tags: visible-light

When viewing a Silver Colloidal substance is there a specific color laser beam that will highlight only silver particle smaller than 100 nanometers  or microns smaller than .01...yet not highlight particles larger than 100 NM ?

Answer (score 0):

In general no there isn't. In fact when you get to particle sizes comparable to the wavelength of the light the scattering becomes very strong and will swamp the scattering from the smaller particle sizes.

It is possible to separate the light scattering from different particle sizes by looking at the autocorrelation of the light. This is how commercial particle size measuing kit like the [Zetasizer](https://www.malvern.com/en/products/product-range/zetasizer-range/?gclid=CjwKCAiA8bnUBRA-EiwAc0hZk0lZONB_efRs_J2hV2x0GHHnrpyvjz3mwyivsdbZ3B_wRgYCv-NC0BoCc-oQAvD_BwE) works. However my previous caveat applies. If there is any significant concentration of the large particles they will dominate the scattering and the measurement will be impossible.